# Objective C / iPhone: How do I extract the actual unicode date format strings for the current region?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, date, format

According to this site:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatter-examples.html

there is a class that handles formatting, which takes in a set of constants/enums (e.g. NSDateFormatterShortStyle) to the "setDateStyle" property/method.

Somehow the NSDateFormatter knows to retrieve the proper locale-specific date format.  What I want is to be able to retrieve the default formats based on the user's choice of region format.  I have a feeling it is stored in NSLocale, but that does not seem to expose anything that will retrieve the format strings.

***Is there a way to extract the formats?  It has to be in memory somewhere; I'm hoping the retrieval mechanism is exposed somewhere.***

I've looked in several places, but the only answers I get are a lesson on how to create an NSDate from a custom format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateFormat = [df dateFormat];
NSLog(@"Date format: %@", dateFormat);
[df release];
```

Just tested on OS X but this should also work in iOS.

Comment: Awesome, it does work.  However if you use the combination date/time picker, the control knows to cut off the year (yyyy).  How does it know to do this properly -- is the format stored somewhere else or does it perform internal parsing of the existing formats?  For an example, use the US format to see the year cut off.  Then switch the region to Bulgaria.  The text is moved around, but the Bulgarian formats (NSDateFormatterShortStyle, LongStyle, etc) do not match it at all.

Comment: I asked the question here instead of as a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858277/objective-c-iphone-how-does-the-date-time-picker-format-its-dates-e-g-strip